# How create multiple pages on one FORM without showing tab pages

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, multipage

I want to create multiple pages on one `Form` without showing tab pages!
How can i do that?
Can using [Telerik PageView](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/pageview/overview) Solve this issue?
How can i hide Telerik PageView's header of pages?

---

I can add multiple panels to the form.
But for all of them : `Dock = Fill`
So i have problem to view under panels & design them.
How can i switch between filled panels?

---

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rtGpZGyjZY) shows a trick.
But what is the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For hiding the tab pages you just need to put this code on form load.

```
this.tabControl_Main.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;
this.tabControl_Main.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1);
this.tabControl_Main.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
```